# How to fill missing json keys with key and null value?

Tags: python, json, etl, apache-beam

For example, I`m doing a ETL with json file, and sometimes some jsons keys don't come with this file, so I need to fill the missing key and value with the missing key and null as the value.

This is a example of json file:

```
"data" :{
"data_info" :{
"version" :value ,
"data_name" : value ,
"data_number" : value ,
"package_name" : value
}
```

Here is the scenario where the missing fields came:

```
"data" :{
"data_info" :{
"data_name" : value ,
"package_name" : value
}
```

And here what I was thinking to do:

```
"data" :{
"data_info" :{
"version" :null ,
"data_name" : value ,
"data_number" : null ,
"package_name" : value
}
```

I`m using apache beam with python SDK, and tried this, but without success...

```
def fill_missing_keys(data):

  data = json.loads(data['metadata'])
  data = {'data': {'data_info': data.get("data_name", None)   {'version': data.get("version", None) , 'data_name': data.get("version", None)... }
  
  return data
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `get()` on the nested dictionary.

```
data = {
    'data': {
        'data_info': {
            'data_name': data['data']['data_info'].get('data_name'),
            'version': data['data']['data_info'].get('version'),
            'data_number': data['data']['data_info'].get('data_number'),
            'package_name': data['data']['data_info'].get('package_name')
        }
    }
}
```

When using `.get()` the result defaults to `None`, it's not necessary to specify it explicitly.

A less verbose method would be to provide a default dictionary and use the `.update()` method to merge the values from the JSON into it.

```
data = {
    'data': {
        'data_info': {
            'data_name': None, 
            'version': None, 
            'data_number': None, 
            'package_name': None
        }.update(data['data']['data_info'])
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps also include the default value ```None```?  i.e.  ```....get('data_name', None)```?

Comment: That's the default default value when using `.get()`.